# Unable to load main page to webscrape and next page doesn't change url

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape data from: http://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/
The first landing page can be accessed by going to the url above and clicking on the orange button "Cari sekolah". 
[image]

The resulting page has the following url: http://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/index.php/chome/pencarian/. Unfortunately, when url is launched, the result is a page stating specified url cannot be found.

Also, how do i go to next pages if when i click the 2nd, 3rd, etc pages the url doesnt change? 
[image]

Grateful if you can help, my code so far - havent gotten far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
import pandas as pd

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--incognito')

webdriver = "/Users/rainer/Desktop/learnpython/web/chromedriver"

driver = Chrome(executable_path=webdriver, chrome_options=option)

url = 'http://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/index.php/chome/pencarian/'

driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Have you tried to submit ?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by submit?

Comment: To submit the form from the first page. It will show you the second page.

Comment: Can you share how to do that? I tried using driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text() = 'Cari Sekolah']").click() but it doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Cari Sekolah']"))).click()
```

Import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Once you reach the `next` page you need to click each `page button` to go `next page`.For an example I have provided range to 15 page you can increase the count.

```
url="http://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/"
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Cari Sekolah']"))).click()
for i in range(2,15):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='list']//a[text()='" + str(i) + "']"))).click()
        print("page number #" + str(i))
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        print("No such element")
        break
```

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--incognito')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
url="http://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/"
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Cari Sekolah']"))).click()
for i in range(2,15):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='list']//a[text()='" + str(i) + "']"))).click()
        print("page number #" + str(i))
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        print("No such element")
        break
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works. To go to next page, it doesnt seem to work. The html code is <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="paging(2)">2</a>... any advice on how to select this?

Comment: @rs26 : Have you seen the code i have provided for next page?

Comment: Yes, i have copied the code above. but the page doesnt seem to load to show new entries for page 2. It returns "no such element", so i think the first portion of try doesn't work

Comment: @rs shouldn't be I have tested both normal chrome and incognito mode.Both are working fine.what error are you getting?

Comment: There is no error.. it's just that when the code goes to the for loop, it prints no such element.. :(.. sorry for asking a lot of questions, still learning how to do this

Comment: @rs26 : Not sure buddy you can see attached screenshot of my execution.

Comment: you can increase the `WebDriverWait(driver, 30)` inside for loop to check if there any difference?

Comment: Thanks so much.. lifesaver! cant seem to get it to work.. anyway, for my own learning can you share the logic behind the syntax: text()='" + str(i) + "'

Comment: This will identify the page number on the web page 2,3,4,5....so on.where I have done string concatenation.